# Why does my ViewController not respond?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class

I have a class set up with a UIImageView and I want to add that to the main viewcontrollers view, but it doesnt work.

Here is my code, Im sure theres something obvious missing:

MyViewController.h:

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   #import "ImageClass.h"

   @class ImageClass;

   @interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
   }

   @end
```

MyViewController.m:

```
   #import "MyViewController.h"

   @implementation MyViewController

   - (void)viewDidLoad {


ImageClass *test = [[ImageClass alloc] init];

[test draw];

[super viewDidLoad];
   }
```

ImageClass.h:

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import "EnkelBildeKlasseViewController.h"


   @class MyViewController;

   @interface ImageClass : NSObject {


MyViewController *maincontroller;

UIImageView *image;



      }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *image;

    -(void)draw;

      @end
```

ImageClass.m:

```
   #import "ImageClass.h"
   #import "MyViewController.h"

   @implementation ImageClass
   @synthesize image;

      - (id)init {
       if ((self = [super init])) {

        }
     return self;
    }



    -(void)draw {


maincontroller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


image = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

image.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

image.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);

[maincontroller.view addSubview:image]; 


     }
```

Nothing in the main viewcontroller changes.. What is wrong?

I have also tried to connect it with IB:

```
        IBOutlet MyViewController *maincontroller;
```

But it still doesnt respond! What should I do?

Comment: I can not see any allocation & initialization for the main Controller. May be you can make a property on the ImageClass for the main controller and set it to self before calling [test draw];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do your drawing in drawRect:, and you need to make imageClass a UIView subclass, and add it as a subview. See this tutorial: http://littlecomputers.net/2010/?page_id=41

Comment: I do not have to do my drawing in drawRect:, the main question was if I could access the image and add it, I found a workaround using your suggestion (UIView subclass) and it worked.